# How to bind Json data with KendoUi

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am new to KendoUI.I want to bind json data with kendoui. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first use [google](http://www.google.com) and look for some tutorials and documentation like [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) to get some basic knowledge. And then look for more precise exsamples like [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction).